# WSGI : Python : my function is probably not doing a "single pass" when trying to replace html characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

The problem is.. the esc function. 
when i leave only 1 item in that function
it actually works ok.

but when i have all those replace lines..
i think it is doing multi pass and thus i end up with..

```
&lt;img src=&quot;&quot;&gt;
```

on the web rather than

```
<img src="">
```

..

```
# coding: utf-8

def esc(a):
    a = a.replace("<", "&lt;")
    a = a.replace(">", "&gt;")
    a = a.replace('"', "&quot;")
    a = a.replace("'", "&#39;")
    a = a.replace("&", "&amp;")
    return a

def application(environ, start_response):
    b = '<img src="">'
    b = esc(b)
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    yield b
```

Comment: Move 5th line on top

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import html
def esc(a):
  return html.escape(a)
```